# Наследование классов

Tags: java, android

Наследую 2 класса от того, что ниже. В первом случае анимация работает, во втором нет. Почему так может быть?

```
public class Entrance extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
TextView textView9;
String toDo;
Animation anim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

imageView.startAnimation(anim);

new MyTask().execute();

textView9.setText(fio2);
}
```

Первый:

```
public class MorningActivity extends Entrance {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.activity_morning);
toDo = "пришел(-а)";

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim);

textView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Воторой:

```
public class EveningActivity extends Entrance {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_evening);
    toDo = "ушел(-а)";

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_moon);
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim2);

    textView9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: Это чудо, в первом случает работает. `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` должен вызываться всегда первым. ДО всего чего угодно остального.

Comment: тогда крашится с NullPointerException на imageView.startAnimation(anim); получается, что вызов анимации раньше ее определения

Answer (score 1):

решилось выделением анимации в отдельную функцию и добавлением ее после определения вьюх в классы наследники

Comment: Все верно, без рефакторинга было никак.

Answer (score 1):

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` всегда должен вызываться перед вашим кодом, а чтобы совместить с вашей реализацией, нужно сделать родителя абстрактным.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageView.startAnimation(anim);
    new MyTask().execute();
    textView9.setText(fio2);
}
```

заменить на

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageView.startAnimation(getAnim());
    new MyTask().execute();
    textView9.setText(getFio());
}

protected abstract void getAnim();

protected abstract void getFio();
```

и у наследников переопределять.